# Android set Text in Dialog 1 from Dialog 2?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have 2 Dialogs. One is a Normal Input Dialog, and the second is a DatePickerDialog. What I am trying to do is set the Content of one of the TextView is the First Dialog to the Date selected in the DatePickerDialog as Follows:

DIALOG 1:

```
public void showEventDialog() {
    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.post_event_dialog);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

    // VIEWS:
    ...

    dateText = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.eventdate);
    dateText.setTypeface(MainActivity.textMain);
    dateText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDateDialog();
        }
    });

    ...

    dialog.show();
}
```

AND DIALOG 2:

```
 public void showDateDialog() {
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            dateText.setText("Test");
        }

    }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    fromDatePickerDialog.show();
}
```

However when I Try to set the Text of the TextView in the First Dialog I get a NullPointer exception. How do I do this properly? I know this must be a very trivial Issue, but I simply cannot wrap my head around it. 
Thank you

Comment: Post your NullPointerException log. It will tell you the line where it crashed.

Comment: As I said: When I set the Text of the TextView. So this Line: dateText.setText("");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, there is no reference of `TextView dateText`  in Second dialog, as It always remain **NULL** (Its only available after initializing from First dialog)

Just pass your `dateText` reference to `showDialog()` Like,

```
    public void showDateDialog(final TextView dateText) {
        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                dateText.setText("Test");
            }

    }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    fromDatePickerDialog.show();
}
```

And call like,

```
showDateDialog(dateText);
```

Comment: I have been Programming for Several Years now. And I am hitting myself for not thinking of this. Thank you.

Comment: It happens.  Happy Coding.. :)